# Cauchy's Integral Question Complex Number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have a question and I'm kind of stuck, I was wondering if you were able to help me move forward.

The question is, 
Use Cauchy's integral formula to evaluate,

$$
\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz
$$

where $|z| = 1$ is oriented counter-clockwise.  Using this result, evaluate the real integral

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2\cos(t)}\cos(2\sin(t) - t)dt
$$

**I have gotten to this step,  and I'm stuck. I have uploaded an [image](http://postimg.org/image/qkm25scfv/). Please do let me know if its unclear, ill rewrite it and upload another picture because Im not familiar with LaTex.
Here's my work:**

$$
|z| = 1 \text{ as } z(t) = e^{it}, t\in [0, 2\pi]
$$

\begin{align}
\int_{|z|} =&\ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2e^{it}}}{\left(e^{it}\right)^2}ie^{it}dt \\
=&\ i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}e^{2\cos(t) + 2i\sin(t)}dt \\
=&\ i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{2\cos(t) + i(2\sin(t) - t)}dt
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z)=e^{2z}$$

Using:

$f'(z_0)=$[image]

$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int _\gamma \frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz$$

$$f'(0)=2$$

The answer becomes: $$4 \pi i$$

Comment: Its the right method and I know this leads to the right answer but how do I solve it using the Cauchy Integral method.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Remember that $$e^{i(2 \sin t-t)} = \cos(2\sin t-t)+i\sin(2\sin t-t)$$

Follow the substitution through and then consider real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Is there anything that can be said about symmetry here?  $\sin(2\sin(t) - t)$ is an odd function and $\cos(2\sin(t) - t)$ is an _even_ function...but the problem is that the domain isn't symmetric (with respect to odd/even-ness).  But then that confuses me even more because why must we choose $t \in [0, 2\pi)$?  Why not _any_ range which encompasses a full cycle?  This seems to suggest to me that all of the integrals from $x$ to $x + 2\pi$ must be equal (but I don't see how that's the case)???

Comment: I'm still stuck on this step :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are using a method when $cos \theta$ or $sin \theta$ should be in the integration.The simple method is either use cauchy integral formula or cauchy residue theorem.

$f^{(n-1)}(z_0) =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^n}$

Comparing this with your integration, $f(z) = e^{2z}, z_0 = 0, n=2$ and $C$ is $|z| = 1$.

check whether $z_0 = 0$ lies within $C$. (yes) so apply the above formula.
Find $f'(z) = 2 e^{2z}$ and substitute $z = 0$. we get $2e^0$.
the answer is $2.2 \pi i$ = $4 \pi i. $